# How to solve memory leak at assigning string value

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, instruments

I have have observed that there is a memory leak at this code. I have released the workingEntry at this class.

```
self.workingEntry.duration = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d",[result minute], [result second]];
```

I inspect this using instruments in Xcode. How can i solve this kind of memory leak?

Comment: You can start by providing more information about the `duration` property.

Comment: duration is a property of VDRec.workingEntry is a object of VDRec.

Comment: When you are working with `ARC` there should be no memory leak. Otherwise you have to dealloc the `duration`.

Comment: I am not working with ARC because some thirdparty fameworks i have used are not ARC compatible.

Comment: add -fno-objc-arc to the compiler flags for the files you don't want ARC. In Xcode 4, you can do this under your target -> Build Phases -> Compile Sources.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Zombies turned on in Scheme:Diagnostics then memory will not be released and everything will look like a memory leak. Only test for memory leaks with Instruments if Zombies is turned off.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you alloc init and release when you releasing workingEntry manually.

```
self.workingEntry.duration = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d",[result minute], [result second]];
```